# Changing one element in a two-dimensional vector changes all elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I'm coding a checkered board game where the board is a two-dimensional vector that holds a `Square` object, and the `Square` holds a `Piece`. Using a nested for-loop, I'm initializing a new `Square` object in each slot in the 8x8 vector - but when I add a `Piece` to one `Square`, it's adding a `Piece` to every single `Square`. I think that, somehow, each slot in the vector is only pointing to one `Square`, even though I'm initializing a new `Square` every time.

I've tried this with a two-dimensional vector of `Square` objects as well as with a vector of `Square` pointers. Currently I'm using the vector of pointers: `vector<vector<Square*>> _board;`

```
    // initializing an empty board
    _board = {{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}};

    // adding a new Square to each of the 8x8 slots
    string colorAlternator = WHITE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            _board[i].push_back(new Square(colorAlternator, make_tuple(i,j)));
            if (colorAlternator == WHITE) {
                colorAlternator = BLACK;
            } else {
                colorAlternator = WHITE;
            }
        }
    }

    // placing a piece 
    /* placePiece() is a function of Square
     * (p2Pieces.at(0) is a piece being pulled from elsewhere)
     */
    _board[0][1]->placePiece(*p2Pieces.at(0));
```

In another function called `view()`, it prints out a visualization of the board (excuse my inelegant implementation, it will be fixed with a for-loop shortly!):

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << BORDER << endl;
        cout << i + 1 << " " << "| "
             << board[i][0]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][1]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][2]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][3]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][4]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][5]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][6]->displayToken() << " | "
             << board[i][7]->displayToken() << " | " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
```

This should be printing every `Square` as being blank except for the one I placed the `Piece` in - but it's printing each `Square` out as containing the `Piece` I just added.

Any ideas what's causing each slot in the vector to be linking to the same `Square`? (Or is that even what's happening?)

*update:* here is the implementation for `placePiece()`, `displayToken()`, and supporting method `containsPiece()` in class `Square`:

```
Piece* _piece;

void Square::placePiece(Piece &piece) {
    _piece = &piece;
}

bool Square::containsPiece() {
    return _piece != nullptr;
}

string Square::displayToken() {
    string displayStr = "  ";

    if (containsPiece()) {
        displayStr = _piece->getToken();
    }

    return displayStr;
}
```

Comment: `// initializing an empty board` -- Why not simply `_board.resize(8);`?  Also, it isn't a good idea to name your variables with leading underscores.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, thanks - I'm new to C++ and didn't know that was a method I could call. (As for the underscores, that's thanks to the style guides I have to work under.)

Comment: Show the implementation of `placePiece` and `displayToken`. Better still, prepare a [mcve]`. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. Does `Square` have a static data member, by any chance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've added those implementations; and no, `Square` doesn't have any static methods or data members.

Comment: Where and how is `_piece` initialized? What, if anything, ensures that it's equal to `nullptr` in most squares?

Comment: What happens if you replace the first statement in the second loop with: `std::vector<Square*> innerBoard { new Sqaure(colorAlternator, make_tuple(i, j)) };
_board.push_back(innerBoard);`? Note: you shouldn't pre-initialized your `_board` with values if you do this.

Comment: @KimberlyH -- `_board[0][1]->placePiece(*p2Pieces.at(0));` -- You then do this: `void Square::placePiece(Piece &piece) {_piece = &piece;}` -- This is dangerous.  If that item in `p2Pieces` becomes invalidated, your `Square` is now referring to an item that no longer exists.